# Need to get statuses of static files

Tags: javascript, html, css, request, xmlhttprequest

I need to get statuses(http codes) of static files on page.

For example html code contains

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://example.com/theme.css">
<script src="script.js"></script>
<script src="https://example.com/script.js"></script>
<img src="image.png">
<img src="https://example.com/image.png">
```

On output need to get json like this
Only 404 needed.

```
{
  "css": [
    {
      "https://example.com/theme.css": "404",
      "https://example2.com/theme.css": "404"
    }
  ],
    "js": [
    {
      "https://example1.com/script.js": "404",
      "https://example.com/script.js": "404"
    }
  ],
      "images": [
    {
      "https://example.com/image.png": "404",
      "https://example.com/image.png": "404"
    }
  ]
}
```

It must be done with only Javascript.

I am going to use this

```
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
        callback(xmlHttp.responseText);
}
xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, true); // true for asynchronous
xmlHttp.send(null);
```

It is necessary that upon receiving the status, this should not be done by executing a separate GET request to the file.

But I can't find the way how to do this without executing a separate GET request.

Who can find the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If** you are using Server side languages like PHP then i have some idea. eg.

```
<?php
$url= $_POST["url"];
$curl = curl_init(); curl_setopt_array($curl, array( CURLOPT_URL => $url, CURLOPT_HEADER => true, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, CURLOPT_NOBODY => true)); $header = explode("\n", curl_exec($curl)); curl_close($curl); $string = $header[0];
if(strpos($string, "200")){
    echo "200";
}else{
    echo "404";
}
?>
```

Call the above file in AJAX with `url` parameter.

Or write **similar** lines of in your server side. Like (python):

```
s=socket.socket()
s.connect('url',80)
s.send('GET /path HTTP/1.0\r\nHost:hostname\r\n\r\n')
print s.recv(1024) #some lines of headers
```

From the above, in short, it is not possible to get `status code` of file present in any host without sending `request`.

Hence, it is not possible without sending multiple AJAX request (seperate GET requests)

Comment: If then, Can you solve this without using "GET" request? Is there any other way without using "GET" request?

Comment: But, how could you check existence of file without sending any request to file containing server?

Answer (score 0):

I need to make some assumptions here, so please check, whether those are true :-)

- You want to run the code in a browser (i.e. not in Electron or Node.js or a Web Extension).
- You want to save additional network roundtrips (e.g. not making additional requests to throw away the response, because you only need the status).
- You want to process the results further.
- You are asking for static files inserted in HTML (instead of injected with JavaScript).

I'm afraid, you won't get much around making additional requests.

Here are some ideas, you could further investigate:

- Make an additional [HEAD](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/HEAD) request instead of GET

  - This will only ask for the HTTP Headers (body will be empty).
  - Sadly, not all servers support it.
- Use a [Service Worker to intercept the network requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers#Custom_responses_to_requests) and look at the status code before forwarding the response to the browser.

  - I can't tell you, how to get the response out of the service worker.
- Register your JavaScript early on and [intercept the requests](https://blog.vjeux.com/2011/javascript/intercept-and-alter-script-include.html), i.e. handle them in JavaScript directly.

  - Does not work with static resources linked in HTML

Would be great if you could provide more details on what you are trying to do.

Cheers

Ryuno-Ki